# Is it possible to create an aggregate table always up-to-date with SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I work with SQL Server and I have different tables

```
TABLE_01
A  |  B  |  D
----------------
1  |  9  |  WW
2  |  2  |  XX
3  |  6  |  YY
4  |  8  |  ZZ

TABLE_02
E  |  F  |  G
----------------
1  |  EE |  WW
2  |  BB |  XX
3  |  CC |  YY
4  |  EF |  ZZ
```

And I'd like to create an aggregate table in order to have KPI always up-to-date (the goal is to increase performance when I want to get the KPI).

```
TABLE_KPI
KPI1| KPI2 | KPI3
----------------
8   |  121 |  12
6   |   85 |  14
4   |  154 |  15
3   |  105 |  20
```

With, for example : `KPI1 = 3*SUM(Table_01.A)/SUM(Table_02.E)`

Is it possible to this ? Am I suppose to do all the triggers related to each tables or there is an easiest way to do this ?

Comment: maybe you mean `VIEW`

Comment: @JohnWoo Well... this could be a solution indeed. I'll try what I can do :)

Comment: I don't think a simple `view` will improve performance, since it will query the original data every time it's called. Perhaps the indexed view suggested by @Mehdi will make the difference here.

Comment: Any 'always up to date' table will incur a performance hit on the source table when you change it. Have you considered optimising the query that retrieves the KPI - i.e. adding appropriate indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create [indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) in order to have a view with physical data that update automatically by SQL Server, and have above performance on select. If you don't want to use Indexed view, need to create trigger for insert, update and delete on Table_01 and Table_02 and manage your data manually (It's have high risk and not suggest).

Comment: @Alex. please say Table_KPI as a view for me. in order to write indexed view of that.

Comment: +1. Found good (while old) explanation here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(v=sql.100).aspx